# How to remove small numbers and text from image using OpenCV in python

Tags: python, opencv, graph, text-extraction, mathematical-morphology

I am performing an graph extraction. I want to remove all the text in the image between X-Y plane like B(2,2) , C(3,3) etc so that the algorithm does not detect them as a line. Can I do that without ocr using morphological operations?
[image: Samples attached]

Comment: given that the text has a different color than anything else (as in the example you posted), you could use `inRange` to filter out/mask/replace the text

Comment: No text can be of any color and at any place in X-Y plane.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to keep the grid, the simplest way is to threshold the image and get a mask. The steps are:

1. Threshold R, G, B separately (keep just the black areas)
2. Apply pixelwise AND - you will get a mask
3. Delete all pixels in the image that are not in the mask.

```
thr = 120
image_thr = np.double(image < thr)
mask = np.min(image_thr, axis=-1)

for c in range(3):
    image[:, :, c][mask == 0] = 255
```

[formatted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYQIv.png)

Comment: good idea....can you please share a snippet for the same in python ?

Comment: Thanks for your answers and code. But that will not work as texts and graph line both can be black as well. If you come up with something please let me know.